# iPhone UIDatePicker very slow

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uipickerview

Im using a UIDatePicker on ModeTime,

but is very slow??

here the code:

```
#import "U2YAccountController.h"

@implementation U2YAccountController
@synthesize timePicker = _timePicker;
@synthesize timeLabel= _timeLabel;  
@synthesize scheduleLabel = _scheduleLabel;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Set title
    self.title = @"Reminder Settings"; 


    CGRect dosageImageRect = CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 62);
    UIImageView *dosageImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:dosageImageRect];
    [dosageImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dosageReminderButton.png"]]; //image was a button, now just image change name of png!
    dosageImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
    [self.view addSubview:dosageImage];
    [dosageImage release];




    UIButton *timeReminderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [timeReminderButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderTimeButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [timeReminderButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 300, 44)];
    [timeReminderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(timeReminderButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [timeReminderButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:timeReminderButton];


    self.timePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 415, 220, 180)]autorelease];
    self.timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [self.timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(timePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:self.timePicker];
    //[self.timePicker setHidden:YES];

    self.scheduleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 64, 200, 20)]autorelease];
    self.scheduleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:12/255.0 green:113/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.scheduleLabel.text = @"Schedule 6 of 7 days";  //updated from web site!!
    [self.view addSubview:self.scheduleLabel];

    self.timeLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(213, 122, 80, 20)]autorelease];
    self.timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:12/255.0 green:113/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.timeLabel.text = @"";
    [self.view addSubview:self.timeLabel];


    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

}
return self;
}


 - (void) timeReminderButtonPressed :(id) sender {


recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)] ;


[UIView beginAnimations:@"PickerUp" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

self.timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 237, 320, 180);

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

[recognizer release];



}

- (void) timePickerChanged:(id) sender {


today = [sender date];


NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

self.timeLabel.text = dateString;


}

- (void) viewTapped :(id) sender {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"PickerDown" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

self.timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 415, 320, 180);

[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

}


- (void) dealloc {

[dateFormat release];


[_scheduleLabel release];
[_timeLabel release];
[_timePicker release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

So why is my picker slow and getting stucked?
what im i missing??

ps. I have commented the nsDateFormatter to find if that was the problem, but no change...

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing to add to previous answer is that you've forgot to commit your animation. I'll even suggest you to use animateWith... methods of the UIView class rather than beginAnimation/commitAnimation as it should be faster (at least by apple).
And one more to go. The gesture recognizer... why not create it with the view at the init time? why create it every time you call the picker?

Comment: thank you!, that was the problem!, I create the gesture recognizer when the picker appears as I need to respond to the tap and hide the picker with this, and disable it when the picker is not showing to use  a button, thanks!

Comment: You can leave the gesture recognizer alive. Just action when needed (when the picker on screen). One little if inside of - (void) timeReminderButtonPressed :(id) sender; and you'll prevent heavy creation/destruction.

Answer (score 6):

My initial reaction:

Allocating an `NSDateFormatter` isn't a cheap prospect.  In your case, you're using the same format string over and over again, so you should REALLY just be allocating a single `NSDateFormatter`, saving it as an instance variable, and then using that when the `UIDatePicker` action fires.  That should speed things up considerably.

Comment: hi thanks, I have changed the code to use an instance variable in the DateFormatter, but still slow,,, what else to change please?, cheers